# Convert String Text File in C to Hexadecimal encoding

Tags: c, encryption, io

Hi I am quite unfamiliar with C but I am trying to do file IO in order to read into a encryption function. The usecase I require is something like this:
The file to read is this: eg
text.txt

```
AA 08 BB CC
BB 00 AA FA
30 //Continues like this
```

Then I need to parse this file and remove the spacing in between as so to read it into word wise segments:
[AA08] -> 1010 1010 0000 1000

At the end, I need to replicate the file condition and write the ciphertext into a similar format with spacing between each bytewise text: lets call this **hexa.txt**

```
AA BB
```

This is my reading code so far but it does not work properly. Firstly i think i should be using fscanf(fhex,"%X", &temp),
however I am unable to get the file to read like this

"AA" -> 170 This means reading the Char as a Hexadecimal Number

ie: A = 1010 in Binary or 10 in Decimal
What I want is to instead of reading "A" in plaintext to a char, i want to read "A" -> BIN: 1010 or if possible read hexa.txt above into a word directly like: 0xAA08, 0xBBCC and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define KEYSIZE 30  
#define WORDSIZE 16
typedef unsigned char HALFWORD;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
int main () {
  FILE * fhex = fopen("hexa.txt", "r");
  unsigned char ch, ch2;
  HALFWORD w = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (feof(fhex)) {
      break;
    }
    ch = fgetc(fhex);// hex value
    if (ch < 47 || ch > 70){
      continue;
    }
    ch2 = fgetc(fhex); // hex value
    printf("%d %d \n", ch, ch2); // value should be 10 10 then 11 11
    // left shift 4 bits and add the other hex digit
    HALFWORD w = (ch << 4) + ch2;
    if (i==0) {
      printf("%8d, Expected: 170 \n", w);
    } else {
      printf("%8d, Expected: 187 \n", w);
    }
    // Encryption code
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Edit:
Added clarity and minimum reproducibility

Edit2: Added comments

Comment: What are the magic numbers 47 and 70? Also show a [mcve]. And read this: [ask]. And what does `"AA" -> 16705` mean?

Comment: Hi @Jabberwocky I have made the recommended edits to this post. My mistake, I meant "AA" -> 0xAA or BIN: 1010 1010 =  DEC: 170

Comment: It's still unclear what the problem is. Your code does nothing (actually it does not even compile). Add some code to print `w` and show the expected vs. actual output.

Comment: Your code does still not compile.

Comment: `ch` and `ch2` are characters. If you read the character 'A', `ch` wil not be `0xA` but `0x41`. You need to add some code that transforms a hexadecimal digit to a hexadecimal nibble. E.g. `0x41` ('A') should be transformed into = `0xA`.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want, but i cant find a way to do this properly. 'rb' mode doesnt help either as it also converts the white space between into numbers

Comment: No one "converts" whitespace into numbers. You will just read spaces with one of your `fgetc` calls. It is up to you to skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example of code to read the file in the format you have.

I made some error checking. And also a function `hexToInt` which convert a string of hexadecimal digits to an unsigned integer, skipping white spaces in front (You don't need that) and stopping on the first non hex digit found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

// Convert a string of ASCII hexadecimal digits to an integer.
// Skip white spaces in front of string and stop at the first no hex digit.
unsigned int hexToInt(const char* hex)
{
    unsigned int result = 0;
    unsigned char c;

    // First, skip spaces
    while (isspace(*hex))
        hex++;
    // Then convert hex digits until no more hex digit
    while (c = *hex++) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            result = (result << 4) + (c - '0');
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            result = (result << 4) + (c + 10 - 'A');
        else if (c > 'a' && c <= 'f')
            result = (result << 4) + (c + 10 - 'a');
        else
            break;  // Not an hex digit, stop converting
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    FILE* fhex = fopen("hexa.txt", "r");
    if (fhex == NULL) {
        perror("unable to open file");
        return 1;
    }
    char line[100];  // More than enough for one of our line
    int lineCnt = 0;
    unsigned short data[1000][2];

    // Read the file and build the array of words
    while (1) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0]), fhex) == NULL) {
            // Read error, assume end of file
            break;
        }
        // File format is "AA 08 BB CC"  (4 hex digit couples separated by space)
        if ((strlen(line) != 12) || // There is a EOL character
            !isxdigit(line[0]) || !isxdigit(line[1]) || (line[2] != ' ') ||
            !isxdigit(line[3]) || !isxdigit(line[4]) || (line[5] != ' ') ||
            !isxdigit(line[6]) || !isxdigit(line[7]) || (line[8] != ' ') ||
            !isxdigit(line[9]) || !isxdigit(line[10])) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File format error on line %d (%s)\n", lineCnt + 1, line);
            return 1;
        }
        if (lineCnt >= (sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "File is too big. Max lines is %d\n", lineCnt);
            return 1;
        }
        data[lineCnt][0] = (hexToInt(line + 0) << 8) + hexToInt(line + 3);
        data[lineCnt][1] = (hexToInt(line + 6) << 8) + hexToInt(line + 9);
        lineCnt++;
    }
    fclose(fhex);

    // Show data read
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCnt; i++)
        printf("Line %d = %X,%X\n", i + 1, data[i][0], data[i][1]);

    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this was brilliant, is there a modification i can do to account for more varieties in file format? For example a line with 3 hexadecimals instead eg: AA BB AA or more hexa in the singular readline

Comment: To support several file formats, you can change the long `if` so that instead of returning an error immediately, one or more `if` check for other file format. And of course the two lines converting the line to the data structure must be adapted for each format. I'm sure you can do it if you fully understand how my code works :-)